# How to define a child class extends from generic class

Tags: java, generics

I am new to java. I am having trouble understanding how  works for classes. For instance, I have a super class Messsage and sub classes StudentMessage and TeacherMessage. Here is code:

```
public class Message<T> {
    protected T messageInfo;
}

public class StudentMessage extends Message {
    protected StudentInfo messageInfo;
}

public class TeacherMessage extends Message {
    protected TeacherInfo messageInfo
}
```

There is Info class as well, which is generic class and StudentInfo and TeacherInfo sub classes extends from Info class.

So when I instantiate StudentMessage object, is it:

```
Message<StudentMessage> studentMessage = new Message<StudentMessage>();
```

and can I access as to StudentInfo by

```
studentMessage.messageInfo //something like this
```

I am not sure If this is the right way to implement what I am trying to achieve. Please help me.

Comment: You need `class StudentMessage extends Message<StudentInfo>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parameterize the class that's being extended:

```
public class StudentMessage extends Message<StudentInfo> { ... }
public class TeacherMessage extends Message<TeacherInfo> { ... }
```

Also, remove the `messageInfo` fields in the subclasses.

Instantiate like:

```
StudentMessage studentMessage = new StudentMessage();
```

Comment: I see. what if we have two generic types in the fields? for example, not just messageInfo, but like messageType? is it still going to be public class StudentMessage extends Message<StudentInfo, StudentType>? or is it not possible.

Comment: Sure, you can do that.